# Margin o Padding, Chart JS

Tags: html5, canvas, chart.js

**¿Hay forma de incrementar el espacio entre la barra y el borde?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de lo contrario, **¿Se puede hacer más fina la barra roja?**

https://jsfiddle.net/palaceslittle/mfvmoy64/215/

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
    labels: ["January"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            borderWidth: 2,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 30, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        }
    ]
};
var option = {

xAxes: {
  gridLines: {
   tickMarkLength: -50
    }
},

};


var myBarChart = Chart.Bar(canvas,{
 data:data,
  options:option
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: cuando dices "mas fina" te refieres a qué exactamente?? que la barra sea mas delgada??

Comment: @LuisAcuña Si, me refiero al ancho. Saludos!